# whats equivalent to flex's viewstack in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to change the view inside stackpanel based on what user clicks from the menubar. What's the best practice to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent, but same functionality can be achieved with several containers from WPF:

- with a Grid (putting all the controls inside the Grid without specifying a row or column for them and implementing a mechanism wich only allows once child to be visible at any time)
- with a Custom Control derived from Panel and a Property specifying which is the active (visible) child from its children, etc.

Comment: but then wouldnt be the design mode useless?

Comment: Depends on the complexity of your children controls and the approach you take for designing them. If you chose to subclass the Panel, you can add a lot of functionality for "design mode", eventually you can achieve exactly the same behaviour as Flex's ViewStack - but you'll have to put some effort into that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use a TabControl with the Header set to nothing